# How to access correctly in each element in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

i have a matrix `B`:

```
B<-structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("2", 
"1", "4", "3", "5"), c("2", "1", "4", "3", "5")))
```

when i try to access to `B[1,3]` it gives me `0` instead of `1`.

i wonder if there is a simple way to access correctly in such matrix in R

Comment: use `dput(B)`, this is illegible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're discovering, using *numeric* indices `i` and `j` gets you the `i`th row and `j`th column --- regardless of what those rows and columns are named. If you instead want the row **named** `"i"` and the column **named** `"j"`, use *character* vectors as your indices.

```
B[1,3]
# [1] 0

B["1","3"]
# [1] 1
```

Quoting from [help("Extract")](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

> i, j, ...
>
> indices specifying elements to extract or replace. Indices are numeric
>   or character vectors or empty (missing) or NULL. Numeric values are
>   coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards
>   zero). Character vectors will be matched to the names of the object
>   (or for matrices/arrays, the dimnames): see ‘Character indices’ below
>   for further details.

Answer (score 2):

In R, using `B[1,3]` refers to the value in the first row and third column. Use quotes to use the rownames and colnames.

```
B<-matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0),nrow=5)
rownames(B)<-c(2,1,4,3,5)
colnames(B)<-c(2,1,4,3,5)

B
  2 1 4 3 5
2 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 1
4 0 1 0 1 0
3 1 1 1 0 1
5 1 1 0 1 0

B[1,3] # first row (named 2) and third column (named 4)
[1] 0

B['1','3'] # row named 1 (which is the second row) and column named 3 (which is the fourth column)
[1] 1
```